# Using the Twitter API with an app - using app OAUTH keys or user logging in

Tags: twitter, oauth

I've built a Twitter app called [Twools](http://twools.it/) in PHP using the wonderful [Twitter API PHP Wrapper script](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php) by [@J7mbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736809/jimbo). Like many Twitter app examples it requires you to create an app at [dev.twitter.com](http://dev.twitter.com/), get the OAUTH keys (consumer key, consumer secret, access token & access token secret) and add them to the app.

I'm happy with the way it works, but I am confused as to the difference between this way of working and apps that allow the user to sign in to use the app.

My Twitter app stores the OAUTH tokens and can run at any time without direction from a user. It could run on a schedule for example every hour. The problem is that it requires a user to create an account at dev.twitter.com and get those tokens.

Other apps seem to allow a user to authorize it to use their details. In this case the user doesn't have to create their own app- the OAUTH details are presumably stored by the app. What is this technique called? I can't seem to find out the difference between these two techniques. In this latter case, once the app has been authorized, can it act autonomously without direction from the user? For example could it run on a schedule?

I hope you can reverse my confusion!

Thanks.

Comment: I think I am on the way of understanding the different ways of connecting to the API. From a bit more research on the Twitter docs (not easy to understand), there are two ways of connecting to the Twitter API using OAUTH:

 1. Application-only authentication - https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth 
 2. Single-user OAuth - https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/single-user-with-examples

Am I looking in the right direction?

Comment: Are you thinking of the [Sign in with Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/sign-twitter) process? I've spent an embarassing amount of time trying to use "J7mbo/twitter-api-php" to request a token only to learn that's not supported (from this [issue](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/issues/44)).... I wonder if there are any libraries that _do_ support this out of the box. If not, maybe I should write one.

Comment: @Jere - possibly, but the Twitter website is far from clear. There is the "Sign in with Twitter" process but also "application-only authentication" and "single user OAuth".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've asked about the three methods of authentication; here's my current understanding:

[**Application-only**](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth): exactly what it says. Your application is assigned one set of access tokens (in addition to the consumer tokens which will be used regardless of auth type). Requests are considered coming from your app and not from a user.

> When issuing requests using application-only auth, there is no concept of a "current user." Therefore, endpoints such as POST statuses/update will not function with application-only auth.

[**Single-user**](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/single-user-with-examples) This is when your entire app only has ONE user total. That's a pretty niche case, maybe something like a single user admin app. If you look at the examples, the tokens are all hard coded. What you are currently doing sounds similar except you are basically asking the user for the values and passing those in. As you noted, it's not ideal. In fact, the first thing on that page says Application-only will usually be more appropriate.

[**Sign in with Twitter**](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter) There are a few steps in the process, but from the user's perspective they get redirected to twitter and agree to grant your application privileges on their behalf. You can then store the return tokens and issue requests.

**I'm pretty sure SIWT is what you're looking for.** Can it run on a schedule? I don't see why not... unless the tokens you get back expire after some time. It also may not be considered a best practice, but I can't find anything saying not to do it.

I'm currently working on implementing this myself (for use as a quick and  dirty log in method) and here is the code for the first stage of the process. The code is quite ugly but works.. you should get the initial oauth tokens back. I smashed my head against a wall for a few days while dealing with an incorrect server time (this can really mess you up) and shared your confusion on the @J7mbo wrapper.

```
$oauthStuffs = array(
'oauth_consumer_key' => "**YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY**",
'oauth_nonce' => base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32)),
'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
'oauth_version' => '1.0',
'oauth_callback' => '**YOUR_CALLBACK_URL**'
);

ksort($oauthStuffs);

$method = 'POST';

$baseUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token';

$outputString = '';

$i = 0;
foreach($oauthStuffs as $key => $value){
    $outputString.= rawurlencode($key).'='.rawurlencode($value);
    $i++;

    if($i < count($oauthStuffs)) $outputString .='&';
}


$baseString = $method.'&'.rawurlencode($baseUrl).'&'.rawurlencode($outputString);

$consumerSecret = "**YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET**";

$signingKey = rawurlencode($consumerSecret).'&';

$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $baseString , $signingKey, true));

$oauthStuffs['oauth_signature']=$signature;

ksort($oauthStuffs);

$headerString = "Authorization: OAuth ";
$i = 0;
foreach($oauthStuffs as $key => $value){
    $headerString .= rawurlencode($key).'="'.rawurlencode($value).'"';
    $i++;
    if($i < count($oauthStuffs)) $headerString .= ", ";
}


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $baseUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($headerString));

$postFields = array(
    'oauth_callback' => rawurlencode('**YOUR_CALLBACK_URL**')
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);


$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
```

If I finish this and I don't learn of another library that supports SIWT out of the box, I may throw it on github.

If none of that works for you, maybe also look at this comparison of authentication methods: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/obtaining-access-tokens

[update: I implemented the whole thing myself and got it to work, but I'd instead suggest looking at  some other libraries such as [abraham/twitteroauth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth)]

Comment: Wow, thanks for this. This certainly clarifies things. Twitter could do with making their docs easier to understand. It would also be great if we could make the PHP Wrapper from j7mbo have SIWT. I've not tried your solution yet, but I'll have a go later. I've never got my head round how call back urls work. In your script are the user's oauth tokens posted to the call back url? Could I then use these in j7mbo's script or have I completely misunderstood this?

Comment: During SIWT, you will send the user to twitter's website so they can see that the whole thing is legitimate and can grant your app access. After that happens, twitter has to send the user back to *your* website. The callback URL specifies where they'll go. Regarding the  tokens, j7mbo's wrapper assumes you have already have 4 token/secrets (consumer, consumer secret, access, access secret). You're using SIWT to *get* the latter two (the user's own access token). With the code I posted, you'll start out not knowing that. After you get them, I think the wrapper could be used as expected.

Comment: OK, I am starting to understand this. I've tested your script (I had to used an alternative to `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` as it's not available to me. Your script returns an oauth_token and an oauth_token_secret. I assume this is randomly generated for the app by Twitter and this can be passed on to the wrapper script. What I don't understand is how I send the user to Twitter in order to grant access to my app? Also, when that happens, I assume the oauth tokens I get back will be for that user? And the wrapper script will have access to that users' Twitter account until revoked?

Comment: The code posted only covers Step 1 in the [SIWT process](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter). Redirecting is described in Step 2 and getting the final access token is in Step 3 (apparently that's the *real* token you need... the first part is only a *request* token... I guess?) If I finish the reset of it, I'll get back to you.

Comment: ah, that makes sense. It should be you writing the Twitter docs! I'll have another look at the SIWT process again, but I just don't understand why Twitter make their docs as clear as mud. If you do get to finish it I would be so grateful if you could get back to me. We'll get there in the end!

Answer (score 1):

This is the question that i hit my head on the wall for several days. But finally i got it.

1. TWITTER CONSUMER TOKEN
2. TWITTER CONSUMER SECRET
3. USER TOKEN
4. USER SECRET TOKEN

These are the things we need to post a tweet on behalf of user, and in this, `TWITTER CONSUMER TOKEN` and `TWITTER CONSUMER SECRET` should be created by the admin of the twitter app for whom/which requires permission to post on user behalf. And the `USER TOKEN` and `USER SECRET TOKEN` are the things that you need from user to post a tweet on his behalf. You can get this by using `getRequestToken()` function of OAUTH. To know how to use this function, please check `redirect.php` in `twitteroauth` written by Abraham [here](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth). And after getting `USER TOKEN` and `USER SECRET TOKEN` you can use your TWITTER CONSUMER TOKEN and TWITTER CONSUMER SECRET with the user's user token and user secret token received from the api to post on his/her behalf. Thats it!

But user can revoke the access anytime by visiting,

https://twitter.com/settings/applications and click on "Revoke Access" button next to your app.

Answer (score 0):

check this out, maybe it's what you want

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#6536

sorry, for my bad English

Comment: You should add a description to what the links have that could help.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately your links aren't really to do with my question in terms of the difference in how your connect with the Twitter API